# Codeigniter Ion auth email unauthenticated

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail

i try to send email with codeigniter and ion auth but i have problem.
there is a red question mark icon on gmail when I send an email like this
[The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Mrs.png)

this is ion auth email configuration :

```
$config['use_ci_email'] = TRUE; 
$config['email_config'] = array(
    'protocol' => "smtp",
    'smtp_host' => "mail.designboug.com",
    'smtp_port' => "587",
    'smtp_user' => "support@designboug.com",
    'smtp_pass' => "asasqwqw123",
    'charset' => "utf-8",
    'mailtype' => "html",
    'newline' => "\r\n",
    'crlf' => "\r\n"
);
```

i hope you can help me guys, thanks

Comment: What does "red question mark" mean?

Comment: hi @Don'tPanic like this

http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Gmail-unauthenticated-avatar-web-screenshot-001.png

Comment: Nobody here wants to go look at off-site screenshots (me included). If Gmail shows a red question mark, it probably means something, and Gmail help probably describes it, right?  So what does it mean?

Comment: i was update the quoestion, please see it :)